# When to use "write" and when to use "write down"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I wrote "Write your phone number" and a native English speaker told me that I had to add a "down". Why is this? When should I add the down and when I shouldn't?

Comment: @NathanTuggy it cannot be flagged as a "duplicate" of a question for which no answer has been accepted.  What's the appropriate resolution?

Comment: @Andrew: Hmm, I voted to close when the answer was scored 1; you could upvote it if you think it's correct and useful, or find a different dupe.

Comment: @NathanTuggy  Sorry, I mean if I try to close this question as a duplicate of the other, I am not able because that question (in your link) has no accepted answer.  Can a moderator accept an answer on behalf of the questioner?

Comment: @NathanTuggy aside from the fact that it's not really a very good answer to the question, that is.

Comment: @Andrew: The answer doesn't have to be accepted. (This is fortunate, as the only one who can accept an answer is the OP.) It just has to have a positive score *or* be accepted.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I see, before it had a positive score, but someone voted it down.  But since the answer there is not very good, should someone edit it?